# Frequent Message Manager - Easily store and send frequently used messages in chat?

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot

[image: The menu that pops up when you click the button.]

### About

Have you ever said something in chat that made you think *"I know I've said this many times before?"* Perhaps you have a few common links that you reply to questions with on a frequent basis. Well now you can save yourself the trouble of digging them up everytime you need them. This handly little UserScript can store and recall common messages (with markdown) and provides options for managing them as well. The script comes with an animated menu interface that is both smooth and intuitive.

#### License

[The MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

You can download the script here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/message_manager.user.js

#### Platform

This script will run on any browser that can run UserScripts (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera). The browser must also support HTML5 storage (all recent browsers do).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

#### History

- **v1.03**

  - Added ability to edit existing messages
  - Made a few animation tweaks
  - Switched links next to messages to icons
- **v1.02**

  - Focus is now set automatically to the text entry.
  - All actions are now animated.
- **v1.01**

  - Added more styles and animations.
  - Switched from JavaScript `prompt()` to inline editor.
  - Corrected bug that popped up when newlines were used in a message.
- **v1.0**

  - Initial release

Comment: `v1.03 RC1 - Fixed escaping bug` - I got you @GeorgeEdison :P